# How to add a single label to a stacked bar chart in GGplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, stacked-chart

I'd like to add a single numerical label to a stacked bar chart in GGplot2.

I have the following code:

```
   # Load the packages
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

# Create a data set called M
M <- structure(list(X1 = c("Diversity", "Endangerment", "Marketability", "Total"),
B1 = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6), B2 = c(3.5, 
3, 3.2, 3.1), B3 = c(1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5), Petal.Width = c(7.1, 
4.7, 3.2, 5.1)), .Names = c("X1", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4"), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")
M

# Plot the stacked bar 
P <- M %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -X1) %>% 
  filter(X1!="Total") %>% #Removes total variable
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  mutate(sum=sum(value)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(variable=reorder(variable, -sum)) %>% #Reorders the chart based on breed total score
  ggplot(aes(variable, value, fill=X1, width =.7)) +
  geom_col(col="black") + #Black border around the bars
  expand_limits(y = 0) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,70), breaks=c(0,10,20, 30,40, 50,60, 70), expand = c(0.02, 0.02))+
  geom_text(aes(label = sum), vjust = -.25)+ #Here the text is added
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2") + #Changes the colour scale
  labs(x="Breed",
       y="Weighted score",
       fill="") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.direction="vertical", legend.position=c(0.9, 0.85), 
        legend.text=element_text(size=11),
        legend.key = element_rect(size = 4),
        legend.key.size = unit(1.5, 'lines'))  # Ensures spacing between the different lines on the legend.
P
```

I want to try and include the "summed" values above each bar. Any ideas how I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

## Answer

So, I created another data.frame, but with summarise then we will just have 1 value of the sum.

### Code

```
df <- structure(list(X1 = c("Diversity", "Endangerment", "Marketability", "Total"),
                B1 = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6), B2 = c(3.5, 
                                                   3, 3.2, 3.1), B3 = c(1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5), Petal.Width = c(7.1, 
                                                                                                             4.7, 3.2, 5.1)), .Names = c("X1", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                      4L), class = "data.frame")

df %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -X1) %>% 
  filter(X1!="Total") %>% 
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  mutate(sum=sum(value)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(variable=reorder(variable, -sum)) ->df

df %>% 
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  summarise(max = max(sum)) ->df_max

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(variable, value, width =.7)) +
  geom_col(col="black",aes(fill=X1)) + #Black border around the bars
  expand_limits(y = 0) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,70), breaks=c(0,10,20, 30,40, 50,60, 70),         expand = c(0.02, 0.02))+
  geom_text(data = df_max,
        aes(label = max, y = max), vjust = -.25)+ #Here the text is added
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2") + #Changes the colour scale
  labs(x="Breed",
       y="Weighted score",
       fill="") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    legend.direction="vertical", legend.position=c(0.9, 0.85), 
    legend.text=element_text(size=11),
    legend.key = element_rect(size = 4),
    legend.key.size = unit(1.5, 'lines'))  # Ensures spacing between the different lines on the legend.
```

### Out

[image: stacked]

Answer (score 0):

If I undestood correctly, you want something like this:
[image: bar]

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl=as.factor(cyl) ) %>% 
  summarise(sum= sum(am)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(cyl, sum))+
  geom_col(width = .5)+
  geom_text(aes(label = sum), vjust = -.25)+ #Here the text is added
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,8.5))
```

Comment: This nearly works, but now I am ending up with three lots of identical totals (placed in each category of the stacked bar) rather than one total on top of the bar as in your example above. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide a reproductible example of your data?

Comment: I have now edited the initial post and added a reproducible example Vinicius.