# Applying a continuous scale while using geom_label_repel based off separate dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2

Based off the approach outline in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50026999/how-to-add-a-single-label-to-a-stacked-bar-chart-in-ggplot2) I have a plot which draws it labels off a separate dataframe. However I was wondering if there would be a way to use `geom_label_repel` instead of `geom_text` but have a continuous colour scale applied to the label?

So the original plot would be:

```
df %>% 
 ggplot(aes(variable, value, width =.7)) +
 geom_col(col="black",aes(fill=X1)) + #Black border around the bars
 expand_limits(y = 0) +
 scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,70), 
                    breaks=c(0,10,20, 30,40, 50,60,70), 
                    expand = c(0.02, 0.02))+
 geom_label_repel(data = df_max,
 aes(label = max, y = max))+ #Here the text is added
 scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2") + #Changes the colour scale
 labs(x="Breed",
      y="Weighted score",
      fill="") +
 theme_bw() +
 theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
       panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
       legend.direction="vertical", legend.position=c(0.9, 0.85), 
       legend.text=element_text(size=11),
       legend.key = element_rect(size = 4),
       legend.key.size = unit(1.5, 'lines'))
```

My guess, if it's possible, its going to include a variation of `scale_fill_gradient` but I haven't found a way to make it work?

If I include a `scale_fill_gradient` like this:

```
 df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(variable, value, width =.7)) +
  geom_col(col="black",aes(fill=X1)) + #Black border around the bars
  expand_limits(y = 0) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(data=df_max, aes(y=max), 
                       fill=max,
                       low='blue', mid='green', high='red', midpoint = 10)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,70), 
                     breaks=c(0,10,20, 30,40, 50,60, 70),         
                     expand = c(0.02, 0.02))+
  geom_label_repel(data = df_max,
                   aes(label = max, y = max))+ #Here the text is added
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2") + #Changes the colour scale
  labs(x="Breed",
       y="Weighted score",
       fill="") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.direction="vertical", 
        legend.position=c(0.9, 0.85), 
        legend.text=element_text(size=11),
        legend.key = element_rect(size = 4),
        legend.key.size = unit(1.5, 'lines'))  # Ensures spacing between the 
                                               # different lines on the legend.
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> Error in continuous_scale("fill", "gradient2", div_gradient_pal(low, mid,  : 
>   unused arguments (data = list(variable = 1:4, max = c(15, 14.7, 9.7, 4.1)), 
>   fill = .Primitive("max"))
> ```

Comment: Would one of the continuous color palettes (instead of Dark2) meet your needs? http://www.r-graph-gallery.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/38_Show_RColorBrewers_palettes.png

Comment: Thanks @Jordo82 however, if I change the colour there it affects the main plot and not the secondary dataframe that creates the labels. It's finding a way to reference the secondary dataframe that I can't find